# XCode: When using MapKit, do I HAVE to have a view based app?

Tags: xcode, localization, dictionary, geolocation, mkmapview

I have created the whole of my app in a single view application and just realised that I need to add a map to it, but alas - all the tutorials I see for creating Map Views, start with "Create a view based application"...

So, is there anything I can do, or am I stuck? :)

Many thanks,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not stuck. You can create a map view in a tab bar application or a navigation based application just like any other view. The procedure is just like for any other view, i.e. just set up the view controllers for each view.

There should be plenty of tutorials on both tab bar applications and navigation based applications online. If you'r not familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't need a tab bar in my app though, it's on the front page of the app, and it's only a single view app?

Comment: Are you planning to have a part of your screen as a map or having a button to show a map over the entire screen?

Comment: Part of the screen at the bottom.

Comment: In that case, just add the MapView as a subview like you would with any other view (either in code or IB).